# Is there publishing for people under 18?

Tags: publisher, feedback, young-author

I am under the age of 18 can I publish a book? I have had the rough draft read through many times by professionals, they said I should  get it published, however I'm not sure if any companies will be interested in a book written by a teenager with little to no experience writing professionally. What should I do? Are there any companies that would be interested in my book?

Comment: related; https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/53136/as-a-young-author-how-do-you-make-people-listen

Comment: @LynnGray:  Regardless of whether or  not publishers will be interested in writers under the age of 18, they will all be interested in writers with a good grasp of capitalization and sentence structure.  Check your writing in correspondence with potential publishers better than you checked things in the question you posted here.  Try to **always** write properly.  If you think "well, it doesn't matter here" then maybe you'll think "it doesn't matter" some time when it does matter.

Comment: "I am under the age of 18.  Can I publish a book?<Paragraph break> I have had the rough draft read through many times by professionals. They said I should get it published. I'm not sure if any companies will be interested in a book written by a teenager with little to no experience writing professionally. <Paragraph break>What should I do? Are there any companies that would be interested in my book?"

Comment: Also related, possibly duplicate: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/18591/23927 This is a question we get asked very, very often.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Maybe.
But be careful of scammers which are widespread in publishing new  and naive authors.

You should search references like Writers Market by Writers Digest magazine to see who might want the type of work you wrote.  Then query those that seem like a fit.

Libraries would also have reference material to help you do the search but their sources will be harder to use.

You could always self publish.  But avoid vanity presses and be sure to do the work yourself not pay someone else.

If you submit you should pay to have it edited first.  Be careful as there are scams in editing too and the prices vary from low to high for editors.

Also there are 5 levels of editing.  I presume from the comments you had that you might only need the lowest level of editing to check SPAG.